# Populate empty cell with value from another cell google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, shopify, google-sheets-formula

I have been trying to create a shopify csv in google sheet from another webshop that is quite different, 
What I'm trying to do now is to create handles based on the title name.
So far it's going ok.

But my problem is that the old webshop creates empty blanks that I need to populate in a another column.

```
This is what I have
    **Handle    Title**
    dalashg  Dalas HG  
    <empty>  <empty>
    <empty>  <empty>    
    dalashg  Dalas HG
    <empty>  <empty>
    <empty>  <empty>
    klyftig  Klyftig  
    <empty>  <empty>
    <empty>  <empty>
```

But I would like something like this.

```
**Handle    Title**
dalashg  Dalas HG  
dalashg  Dalas HG  
dalashg  Dalas HG       
dalashg  Dalas HG
dalashg  Dalas HG  
dalashg  Dalas HG  
klyftig  Klyftig
klyftig  Klyftig
klyftig  Klyftig
```

I have tried ifBlank, populate and other different formulas but I'm not so jedi on this.

I have a open google docs with 3 columns where column C is explaining what I would like column A to look like
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JBuKrKStGt_r_Oyz52AFZzaWihDw7zFyAB2CeiRETwY/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an array formula you can place in the `C2`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), FILTER({ROW(A2:A), A2:A}, A2:A <> ""), 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!